# How to code a backtracking method that returns all possible solutions in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, methods, backtracking

I am student and I am stuck on this problem:

The method gets an Array of Items and a certain amount of "money" as an Integer. Every Item has a "prize" and a description. Now I have to find all possible combinations of Items that could be bought with the money. The supply of each Item is infinite and they can be bought several times.

I've managed to come up with a basic Algorithm that returns me the FIRST possible solution, but I have no idea how to get to the point where it returns ALL possible Solutions.

I'm thankful for any input!

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Can you post the sample program you have done so far to get suggestions form community ?
You need to work towards preparing a "collection" of possible items to be bought with certain amount. Precisely iteration over items array till you exhaust the money.

Answer (score 0):

An array of found solutions has a problem: an array is fixed-length in java. Use a `List` instead, and pass that as parameter, to be filled.

Instead of a single solution:

```
Solution s = search(param);
```

do:

```
List<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
search(param, solutions);
for (Solution s : solutions) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

with

```
void search (Param param, List<Solution> solutions) {
    ...
    if (solved) {
        solutions.add(new Solution(...));
        return;
    }
}
```